# Merge statement inserting data with select statement Hana DB

Tags: sql, hana

Assuming that `T1`, `T2`, and `T3` have the same columns. Can we insert the select statement in the merge statement?

```
MERGE INTO "my_schema".t1 USING "my_schema".t2 ON "my_schema".t1.a = "my_schema".t2.a
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT SELECT * FROM t3 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That not possible with the current (HANA 2 SPS 04) version of HANA.

The `MERGE INTO` command only allows for modification (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) of the target table.

`MERGE INTO` is designed to update a single table from one or more source tables.

What you describe is changing multiple tables, which is not supported.

Other DBMS (i.e. Oracle) allow for an additional `ERROR_LOGGING` clause that effectively writes into a second target table. HANA does not have that option so far.